# Access post meta just after publishing

Tags: hooks, post-meta, publish

the following code is supposed to store post meta of the recently published post to the variable $temp. But it doesn't, $temp is always empty. This seems to happen because "transition_post_status" fires before meta information is stored to the database.

Is there a hook that makes me able to get the post meta of the post I just published?

```
function myfunction($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
     if ($post->post_status !== "publish" ) {
       return; }

     $temp = get_post_meta($post->ID);
     // do something with post meta information
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'myfunction', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Please **do not** post duplicates, and **do not** use different accounts to post the same question. You might get help if you stick to **one trusted** account :-)

Comment: Sorry. I posted the other post as a guest and edited it as registered user. For some reason I couldn't add comments to the answers, so I started a new try.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Here is the description of `transition_post_status` from the codex:</strike>

> This function's access is marked as **private**. That means it is not
>   intended for use by plugin and theme developers, but only in other
>   core functions. It is listed here for completeness. Use any of these
>   functions instead.

Why not use the `publish_post` action instead? [There is a nice article + example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post#Example) in the codex which covers your case. It sends an email whenever a post is published and sends the post data.

**Edit 1**: As @Pieter Goosen pointed I've looked at different function (`_transition_post_status()` instead of the hook `transition_post_status`). Please disregard my post about it's description. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `transition_post_status` hook !== `_transition_post_status()` function. Using the `transition_post_status` hook is perfectly fine :-)

Comment: Aaah yes. My bad. Missed the underscore and trusted Google a bit too much (Lazy level +1). Will edit post not to mislead somebody.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But the problem is, I can't access meta data of the post via get_post_meta(), which outputs an empty array. But I need to get access to the meta data, because one of them is an automatically generated ID, not identical to the ID of the post itself.

Comment: I have tried `publish_post`, `save_post`, `transition_post_status` hooks - all of them didn't return the meta data of the post. `wp_insert_post` did it, but it fired 76 times, I need it to do it just once. Anyone an idea how to solve that?